# Facebook Audience Network NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, facebook, android-proguard

I'm using Facebook Audience Network v4.27.0.
The apk compiles fine using Proguard.
Sometimes this crash occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.d.a (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.d.<init> (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.b.<init> (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.o.<init> (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.m.<init> (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.l$4.c (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.l$4.b (Unknown Source) 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.c.b$1$1.run (Unknown Source)
```

This is the Proguard mapping of the corresponding class:

```
com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.d -> com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.d:
    com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.e a -> a
    android.widget.TextView b -> b
    android.widget.TextView c -> c
    void <init>(android.content.Context) -> <init>
    void a(android.content.Context) -> a
    void a(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> a
    void a(int,int) -> a
```

When I remove all `dontwarn` directives in proguard.txt, the above NoClassDefFoundError is not shown, so the crash probably has nothing to do with missing libraries.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you didn't include Android Support Library v4 or v7.
I also highly suggest updating to latest 5.1.0 version.